# Is it possible to import the array type, in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, import

Is it possible to import the "array type" in Java?

I know this will be a useless import, but we can explicitly import `java.util.String` (although `java.lang` is automatically imported) or even the class that is being defined in the current compilation unit...

Is it possible to make this absurd import?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't import the array type. Like you can't import `int` or `double`

Answer (score 1):

Array is more of a primitive type which are defined by the language. When you write `int[] a = new int[5];` what you're actually doing is setting aside 5 memory locations that can hold a primitive int type. Same thing occurs for any other array declaration. In other words you can't import it from java.

Comment: +1 for mentioning primitives. I'd like to add that most primitive types have `Object`-derived version. (see http://mindprod.com/jgloss/intvsinteger.html for `int` vs. `Integer`) Similarly, java has several collection types (derived from `Object`), such as `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, etc.

Comment: Yes, there are Integer, Float, Double and those are the immutable versions of their primitive types and are also used as wrapper classes because to create Collections with templates you need an object. such as ArrayList<Integer>

Answer (score 0):

You can't and there's no single array type in Java anyway. Array types created from different element types will be different themselves.

It's easy to see this if you try to compile this code:

```
String [] stringArray = new String[4];
Object [] objectArray = new Object[4];
objectArray = stringArray; //This won't work even though individually every String can be cast to Object
```

Comment: You're right. But you can't see it from your example, as `List<String>` isn't compatible with `List<Object>` as well (a parameterized type property that is described somewhere in the JLS). But `objectArray.getClass()` is different from `stringArray.getClass()`, while this doesn't happen with parameterized types.

Comment: True, I didn't want to overcomplicate it with mentioning parameterezid classes. What I should've added though is that you can't even cast an array type into another array type.

Answer (score 0):

it's unnecessary. Once type `T` is understood, `T[], T[][], T[][][]...` are automatically understood. This is true for both compiler and runtime. *Effectively*, once `T` is imported, all `T[]...` are imported; once `T` is loaded by a classloader, all `T[]...` are loaded by the same class loader.

Comment: I know it is unnecessary. I just wanted to know if it was **possible**. But it isn't.